# Python - Flask и Tkinter()

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

Идея такова, есть два юзеринтерфейсас, один через `GUI` с помощью `Tkinter`, другой через `Web-API (Flask).`

Написал код который запускает `Flask` с функцией логина и `Tkinter`, с кнопками. 
Проблема такого что, если к примеру, `Flask` запускается первым, не работает `Tkinter`, пока не завершится или не убить процесс `Flask`, после этого, только возможно управление через `Tkinter`, так и наоборот.

Если ли способ реализации управление того и другого в одно и то же время?
Другими словами, управлять можно было бы через обычный и привычный `GUI` и через `WPI`.

Comment: Без информации, как конкретно всё описанное реализовано и интерфейса к чему, на вопрос не ответить

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, приеду домой и напишу более развернутое описание.

Comment: В разных потоках/процессах запускать?

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать два независимых приложения: сервер с использованием Flask, клиент на Tkinter. Приложение на Tkinter шлет серверу HTTP запросы, тот отвечает.

Comment: @m9_psy в одном, они должны работать в одно и тоже время.

Comment: @insolor не вариант, так как Web API и Tkinter должны оба отправлять запросы на сервер.

Comment: Не обязателен Tkinter как GUI модуль, можно взять и другой, который будет работать с Flask

Comment: @Insider, тогда два клиента (веб и десктоп). Какой смысл лепить их вместе?

Comment: @insolor то есть два клиента?

Comment: @Insider, две отдельных программы. Одна с веб-интерфейсом, другая с gui через Tkinter. Обе шлют запросы на сервер. Запускаются независимо друг от друга, никто никому не мешает.

Comment: Общие части можно вынести в отдельные модули, естественно.

Comment: в отдельные треды прийдется всеравно или сделать гибридный луп

Comment: @eri что такое гибридный луп и есть на него документация? Для Python 2.7.x

Comment: нет документации на то что еще не изобретено)
для работы тк и фласка нужны лупы, это основные циклы программ. чтоб работало и то и то - нужно запустить оба этих цикла. или создать свой цикл, который будет работать за двоих.

Comment: проще раскидать по тредам, но возможно всплывут новые проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, на котором можно сделать запуск тк и фласка.

```
import flask
import treading
import Tkinter

root = Tk()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

#класс или функции самой программы

def flask_main():
    #код для фласка писать тут
    app.run(port=5001) #запуск лупа

def tk_main():
    #код для тк тут
    root.mainloop() #запуск лупа тк

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flt = treading.Tread(target=flask_main)
    flt.daemon = True
    flt.start() #фоновый процесс

    tk_main() #основной поток
```

Дальше есть ньюансы. В root.mainloop() могут возникнуть блокировки, что сделает невозможным обработку во фласке или наоборот.

Comment: попробую и посмотрю какие проблемы или нет все это принесет. Спасибо

Comment: кстати вы забыли о `app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)` нужный для `Flask`

Comment: я тут много не написал - писать код это ваша задача

Comment: это скорее для тех, кто столкнется с такой же проблемой, чтобы они не забыли)

Comment: без секрета работает, он нужен только для авторизации по куки